# Filter through array and find index for splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, angular, typescript

I am looking to filter through an array of objects and find the index of either a matching objects date or the closest date to insert a new object after.

```
let expenseIndex = tempArray.findIndex((a: any) => a.Date <= expense.Date);
tempArray.splice(expenseIndex, 0, expense);
```

The `<=` operator does not seem to work here. If I do `==` and an expense is found with a matching date i get back the index but when nothing matches I get `0` or `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming the temp array ist sorted by date):

```
temp = temp
  .filter(v => v.Date <= exp.Date)
  .concat(exp, array.filter(v => v.Date > exp.Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

angular provides the index when using `*ngFor` directive.

You can get the index of the current like shown below

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" 
     (click)="doSomethingWithIndex(i)">
  {{item.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: The question points out that I need to insert a "new" object into the array. The example you have works with existing objects. Thanks anyways